# substitute values in email via python

Tags: python

substitute values in email via python

I am NEW to python and trying to write a script that will send an email (In HTML) to a group of people.

This python script will execute a perl script that will read an excel file and save it in a .txt file, once the file is created the python script will open the txtFile and create an array of all the names:

Here is the snip from the scripts

```
file = open(txtFile, "r" )
array = []
for line in file:
    array.append( line )

print array[2]
print array[1]
```

$ ./tempSendOnCall.py
Branch number is 2011.06
07-15-11
Ash dy
Joe Des

Once this part is over I am creating an email (In the same script) that will send it out and I need to replace the names of the oncall and lead on call persons with the results from the Array as this changes every week.

Here is the email portion:

```
sendmail="/p4/sendEmail"
SERVER = "ServerName"

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

me = "name@domain"
you = "name@domain"

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "3LS / QA / SA on-call review"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

text = "test"
html = """\
<html>
  Message
  Hi Ash dy, (Need to be updated from Array[1])
     starting on DATE (Should ready from date = time.strftime("%m-%d-%y"))

  Joe Des (Should be replaced with Array[2]) is the 3LS lead for this week.\n

  Let me know if you have any questions,

"""

part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

s = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

I have everything working for me, but I can't find a way to replace the Array values, or date, within that email!!

Please help :-)

-guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow me to direct your attention to the [format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec) string function

```
html = """\
<html>
  Message
  Hi {0:}, (Need to be updated from Array[1])
     starting on {1:} (Should ready from date = time.strftime("%m-%d-%y"))

  {2:} (Should be replaced with Array[2]) is the 3LS lead for this week.\n

  Let me know if you have any questions,

""".format(Array[1], time.strftime("%m-%d-%y"), Array[2])
```

Of course, it will need access to your Array variable to work.

Comment: Thank you all so much!!!   
I have used Spencer's method and it worked like a charm!!!

Since I had 4 strings that needed to be replaced I used this

    .format(Array[1], Array[2], time.strftime("%m-%d-%y"), BRANCH)


Thanks
guy

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dict` to substitute your fields ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)). Example:

```
>>> Array = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
>>> "some text %(a)s --more text %(b)s at %(c)s" % {"a":Array[1], "b":time.strftime("%m-%d-%y"), "c":Array[2]}
'some text bar --more text 07-15-11 at baz'
```